# Prove that there exists an $n × n$ matrix B such that $AB = 0$ but $B ≠ 0$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let A be an $n × n$ matrix which is not invertible. Prove that there exists an $n × n$ matrix B such that $AB = 0$ but $B ≠ 0$. Why is that? If A = 0 then B can be zero.

Comment: "Can be zero" doesn't mean "has to be zero". You want to prove that B does **not** have to be zero. The hinted answer below is very good.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** Let $B$ consist of identical columns that are contained in the null space of $A$. The null space of $A$ is non-trivial since $A$ does not have maximal rank.

Comment: What is a null space?

Comment: Also I don't know what rank is. This problem is in the 1st chapter of hoffman kunze.